Issues Configuring Custom Domain with GitHub Pages
I'm having trouble setting up a custom domain for my GitHub Pages site. Here are the details:
enter image description here
enter image description here
I've added the correct A Records and CNAME.
DNS has propagated mostly, but some servers are failing.
My CNAME file at the root of the repository contains www.hmpsmathuho.com.
GitHub Pages settings are configured correctly, but I still get a "DNS check unsuccessful" message.
Here are my DNS settings:
A Records for the root domain (@):
185.199.108.153
185.199.109.153
185.199.110.153
185.199.111.153
CNAME Record for www:
hmpsmathuho.github.io

Successful DNS configuration allowing my custom domain to work with my GitHub Pages site without any errors.
